# What's the error type for in errorformat for Vim’s quickfix list?

Tags: vim, types, errorformat

I’m unsure about the `%t` format specifier in Vim’s quickfix list. How does it affect the behavior/display of the quickfix buffer?

I tried to find it out with the following test file:

```
$ cat test.out
foo              Error         1 foo.h            foobar
bar              Error         2 foo.h            foobar
foobar           Warning       3 foo.h            foobar
barfoo           Warning       4 foo.h            foobar
```

And the following `errorformat` first:

```
set errorformat+=%.%#%*\\s%.%#%*\\s%l\ %f%*\\s%m
```

With this `errorformat` in place I can use `:cgetfile test.out` and jump to the line numbers in `foo.h`, but with the following `errorformat`:

```
set errorformat+=%.%#%*\\s%t%.%#%*\\s%l\ %f%*\\s%m
```

All that has changed is that now I see some spaces after the line numbers in the quickfix buffer, e.g. I see (two spaces after the 1)

```
foo.h|1  | foobar
```

instead of

```
foo.h|1| foobar
```

So I have two questions:

1. What is wrong with my `errorformat`?
2. What should I see if the error type could be extracted?

Answer (score 8):

> I'm unsure about the %t format specifier in Vim's quickfix list, how does it affect the behavior/display of the quickfix buffer?

It tells the quickfix buffer what type of error a match is (error, warning, or informational). The quickfix buffer will then show that information after the line number and highlight it in a different color. For example, here is a warning and an error:

```
hosts.cfg|3473 error| Could not add object property
hosts.cfg|3790 warning| Duplicate definition found for host 'mailgateway'
```

In the quickfix window the word "warning" is in yellow and the word "error" is white on red. In my errorformat I am using %t where the E or W would be in Error or Warning. For example:

```
%trror: %m in file '%f' on line %l
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not really an answer to your question, but an alternate solution I use myself.
Personally I find the errorformat system too complicated, and instead use a common very simple errorformat fed by the output of a real function, that I pipe the output of my make command through.
I use this: "%f\ %l\ %c\ %m".
I write these error parsing functions in python, but any of the supported scripting languages should do, or even vimL.
The logic of this being that such a function is much easier to debug, usable outside of vim, and (at least for me) quicker to write than crafting an errorformat string.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I stumbled upon the error type when I was playing around with ctags -x --c-kinds=f <some file> to get a list of all functions into the quickfix buffer for easy viewing and jumping to them in the file I'm currently visiting. Of course the next thing I was trying was to get all interesting things/tags listed in quickfix and some small identifier to distinguish macros, functions, variables, etc. and the error type looked like a good try...

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following example in quickfix.txt where **%t** is used.

`Examples

The format of the file from the Amiga Aztec compiler is:

    filename>linenumber:columnnumber:errortype:errornumber:errormessage`

```
filename    name of the file in which the error was detected  
linenumber  line number where the error was detected  
columnnumber    column number where the error was detected  
errortype   type of the error, normally a single 'E' or 'W'  
errornumber number of the error (for lookup in the manual)  
errormessage    description of the error
```

`This can be matched with this errorformat entry:

    %f>%l:%c:%t:%n:%m`

It seems that some compiler are storing the error type in a single character E or W, presumably for Error and Warning.

Keep in mind that it is a single character, so it won't match "Warning" or "Error".
    `%t     error type (finds a single character)`

Comment: That much I already know, so an error type is a single letter, but what does quickfix do with this single letter? Should it be displaying it somehow?

Comment: I just had a quicklook in Vim source in ./src/quickfix.c where errorformat are dealt with. I don't exactly see the point of errortype. (Apparently it is always `1` when using the :helpgrep but beyond that...)

Comment: You can have a look there : http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/quickfix.c The error type is stored in the error list but does not seem to be of much use...

Comment: Working link for the source: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/beb9cb19c660484488a71a25eda46ab0fa579278/src/quickfix.c#L40